# Error after formatting julian date to regular dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime, julian-date

So I have the following expression which converts julian date (AS400 date of format yyyy### with #= the calendar number day, ie 2020010 = 2020 january 10, 010 is tenth calendar day):

```
iif([JulianDateTable1]='',format(CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,RIGHT([JulianDateTable2],3)-1,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT([JulianDateTable2],4)))),'YYYYMMDD'), format(CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,RIGHT([JulianDateTable3],3)-1,CONVERT(datetime,LEFT([JulianDateTable3],4)))),'YYYYMMDD')) AS agreementdate
```

When I run this I get the following error though:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string

Not sure if this has anything to do with the date format I'm trying of 'YYYYMMDD' but have also tried 'MMddyy' and have gotten the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a code format option in the question editor... it will make your question a lot easier to read. And the blobkquote option is good for displaying errors.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about both those things! Still relatively new to this site so definitely apologize for any mistakes. Will fix both those now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use date arithmetics to convert this input to a proper date datatype. If the julian date is stored as a string:

```
dateadd(
    day, 
    convert(int, right(JulianDateTable2, 3)) - 1, 
    datefromparts(left(JulianDateTable2, 4), 1, 1)
)
```

If it's an integer value:

```
dateadd(
    day, 
    JulianDateTable2 % 1000 - 1, 
    datefromparts(JulianDateTable2 / 1000, 1, 1)
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ad00f3c0585717d4a238e0db3198ec3)**

Comment: So that seems to work until I need to refer to the expression in the select statement and throws this error "Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid"

Beginning to think the issue is with the data itself